# Property treated as if it's a property of another property?

Tags: c#, class, properties

I'm using simple Unity code as an example because I haven't run into this kind of code elsewhere.

How is this allowed?

```
Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();

renderer.material.color = Color.red;
```

`Renderer` is a class. `renderer.material` here is a property of the `Material` class. That's pretty clear.

Here's the part that I don't understand: `renderer.material.color`, according to Visual Studio, is a property of `Material` class, yet to me it seems as if it's treated here as a member of `Renderer` class. I don't understand how it works.

It also looks to me as if the `color` property is a property of another property (`material`), but I'm not aware of such concept existing either in C#. What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks to me like renderer has a property called material and material has a property called color? What’s odd about this?

Comment: `material` here is a property of the `Renderer` class. How could a property possibly have a property? That's what I was asking here. If you mean that `color` is a property of `Material` class it still doesn't make sense to me, because the `color` property is accessed as if it's a member of the `Renderer` class.

Comment: @boulder The property is **of type** `Material` and that type has a property `color`. Why is this weird for you?

Comment: Consider a class called `Company`. One of the properties of `Company` is `President`. The `President` property is of type `Person`. One of the properties of the `Person` class is `PrimaryAddress` which of type `Address`. The `Address` class has a `string` property named `City`. Assuming I have a properly initialized `Company` object in a variable named `myCompany`, I could say `var myPresidentsAddress = myCompany.President.PrimaryAddress.City;`

Answer (score 0):

Does it make sense if I break it out like this?

```
Renderer rend = GetRenderer...

Material mat = rend.material;

Color col = mat.Color;

Console.WriteLine("color is "+col+" setting material's color to red..");

mat.Color = Color.red;
```

It's a color inside a material inside a renderer.

It's like this class pair (assume access modifiers are all public and omitted for clarity):

```
class Address{
  string Street;
}
class Person{
  Address HomeAddress;
  Address WorkAddress;
}

...

myPerson.HomeAddress.Street = "1, Infinite Loop";
```

It's just navigating round the graph of objects using `.`; you'll have done it hundreds of times before, I'm sure